# Merge similar Tags in SVG

Tags: c#, svg

I Have an SVG file contains about 20000 path like the following:

```
<rect x="0" y="0" fill="#191915" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="0" y="1" fill="#191915" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="0" y="2" fill="#191915" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="0" y="3" fill="#191915" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="0" y="4" fill="#191915" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="0" y="5" fill="#191915" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="0" y="6" fill="#191915" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="0" y="7" fill="#FF00FF" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="0" y="8" fill="#191915" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="0" y="9" fill="#191915" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="0" y="10" fill="#191915" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="0" y="11" fill="#191915" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="0" y="12" fill="#191915" width="1" height="1"/>
```

etc...

each tag contain the positions for the path, the color fill and it's width & height (always be 1 pixel)
i need a tool to automatic merge the similar connected tags with each other to be one tag for example like :

```
<polygon fill="#191915" points="0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3 0,4 0,5 0,6 1.6 1.5 1.4 1.3 1.2 1.1 1.0"\>
<rect x="0" y="6" fill="#FF00FF" width="1" height="1"/>
<polygon fill="#191915" points="0.8 0.9 0.10 0.11 0.12 1.12 1.11 1.10 1.9 1.8"\>
```

Comment: Try SVG Cleaner for example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009305/what-are-some-options-for-optimizing-svg

Comment: unfortunatly it did not work